# How to fix Ruby getting load path with stray utf-8 character

Tags: ruby, linux, internationalization, virtual-machine

I've got a system that after a little use will result in Ruby being unable to run because of the following error

```
ruby: No such file or directory -- ¯ (LoadError)
```

The last few characters after the `--` and before the `(LoadError)` are a sequence of utf-8 characters. If I keep running ruby I'll get a different few characters each time. Eventually it will pollute my whole shell and I have prompts like the following

```
⎼┤b≤: N⎺ ⎽┤c▒ °☃┌e ⎺⎼ d☃⎼ec├⎺⎼≤ ↑↑  (L⎺▒dE⎼⎼⎺⎼)
[┘┘▒⎽⎺┼c┌▒⎼┐@┌⎺≤▒┌├≤↑de┴↑┘┘▒⎽⎺┼c┌▒⎼┐ c┤⎼⎼e┼├]$
```

How do I solve this? How does it get this way in the first place?

### Notes

- When the text is messed up I can highlight it in Tmux and see what should really be there.
- Pressing ctrl+v ctrl+o causes the error at the prompt to go away until I run `ruby` again.
- Condition persist through reboots
- System is provisioned with chef. That stops once this condition happens because chef uses ruby
- The prompt only goes nuts inside of Tmux. If I use a new terminal without Tmux then the utf-8 error only happens on the error line. The prompt line always stays correct.
- LANG is set to en_US.UTF-8
- Sometimes the extra characters look like part of a configuration file.

  ```
  /usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- cxxflags (LoadError)
  ```

  This shows `cxxflag`. I have also seen `CC` before too.
- The machine is a VM. Rebooting it or the host didn't fix the issue
- Ruby version 1.9.3-p429
- Using CentOs 5.9
- /etc/sysctrl/i18n is setting the LANG to en_US.UTF-8

Comment: What version of Ruby?

Comment: 1.9.3-p429. Although I also saw this before I upgraded.

Comment: You may want to try Ruby 2.0, its unicode support is much better (and it’s the default).

Comment: I cannot switch to Ruby 2.0 yet. My company is trying to get all apps on the same version of Rails and Ruby before going to 2.0.

Comment: Well, it might be worth trying just to know if it’s fixed, and thus know the problem is in Ruby.